# iOS app with trial period

Tags: ios

I searched online but I didn't found any answer.
Is there any way to make an app which can be used regularly for 30 days, and when this period expires the user have to pay to continue using the app?
I hope I was clear and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You could sure create an app intro informing people about the trial period upon first launch, record the current time stamp in the app’s defaults and refer to an in-app purchase when the trial period has passed.

Comment: Apple will reject such an app. They do not allow such apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar feature once, and the simplest solution is to store a UserDefault with the date of the apps first launch. And on subsequent launches of the app compare the date. If the date is greater than 30days you can block features or prompt users to buy the app....etc.

Or you can submit a lite app for free and the full version for a fee.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: But you can't make the app completely unusable after the trial period. You can't make any mention of it being a "trial app".

Comment: I have an app on the Apple store for the past 3 years that completely blocks the UI in certain conditions. And that renders the app unusable until the user completes an action on our website.

Comment: Which one, @OverD?

Comment: @OverD You're lucky Apple hasn't noticed that yet.

Comment: It’s called Ey pilot recruitment app. It’s available on the UAE App Store

Comment: @rmaddy I don’t believe the Apple review process goes into every single line code, if your app is usable during the review process I think your good 

Comment: I can confirm the latter, I have also released apps that were approved initially, and then rejected in some update later on when they found a feature that was implemented day one. Stuff slips through ‍♂️, so OP could just try.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth agreed, never hurts to try